# jquery UI Autocomplete equivalent liblary

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, equivalent

I am searching for Jquery UI autocomplete equivalent.
I can't use jQuery UI in my project.
Any sugestions for some libraries that should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/